# Images not appearing when scrolling down a page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I'm following a tutorial online, and this one has left me stumped after a few attempts and research.
Basically when a user scrolls down the page an image should appear when it peaks at about 50% of it's height from the bottom.

However none of my images are appearing? In the code when I loop through each image to find it's height from the **bottom**, and console.log it shows me it's position no problem.

```
 const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight);
```

When I attempt to divide the height of the image in half console.log shows me *NaN*.

```
const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -
  sliderImage.height / 2;
```

I'm not sure if that's preventing the images from being shown or not? Here is the full section of code I'm referring to.

```
const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.animation-element');

function checkSlide(e) {
  sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
// half way through the image
const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -
  sliderImage.height / 2;
// bottom of the image
const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;
const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
  sliderImage.classList.add('in-view');
} else {
  sliderImage.classList.remove('in-view');
}
```

});
}

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide));
```

The loop is also always showing *false* when I'm scrolling up and down in devTools.

My apologies if I'm not explaining it correctly, still learning. Here is a simplified version of my code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5eog6z42/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the height of a div, not an image:

```
function checkSlide(e) {
  sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
    // get the height of the image, not the div
    const height =  sliderImage.querySelector("img").height;
    const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -
      height / 2;
    debugger;
    // bottom of the image
    const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + height;
    const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
    if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
      sliderImage.classList.add('in-view');
    } else {
      sliderImage.classList.remove('in-view');
    }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5eog6z42/2/

Comment: Of course! Or I could have just added the _animation-element_  class directly to the img tag.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Okay I've added more to my page, however my images are sliding in and out on every scroll? Any ideas?  Thanks again.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjdmeozf/7/)

Comment: @WhatMeWorry I think you can remove the else statement that removes the `in-view` class and images stay visible.